# bno055 IMU doesn't give absolute orientation

Tags: imu, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

For my robot I am using the Adafruit bno055 9DOF absolute orientation IMU. However, the orientation given is relative to it's starting position, not the magnetic north pole.

I have tried using the rtimulib_ros package as well as ros-imu-bno055 but in both cases the result is the same.

I know the magnetometer is working since I can see its output in one of the topics published by ros-imu-bno055 and those values change if I move a magnet close to it, but I'll admit that I don't really know how to interpret that data so I'm not sure what kind of value I *should* be seeing.

The IMU connected to a Jetson Nano via I2C.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360402/bno055-imu-doesn%27t-give-absolute-orientation/) by [anonymous58627](https://answers.ros.org/users/58627/anonymous58627/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is expected behavior. Its absolute orientation relative to startup. Some IMUs won’t even do that fusion for you.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous58627](https://answers.ros.org/users/58627/anonymous58627/) on 2020-08-27**:
I see. Is there an existing package that will allow me to use the magnetometmer to set the origin to the magnetic north?

**Comment by [flynneva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44351/flynneva/) on 2021-02-09**:
hi @jeremie, I've been working on a ROS2 bno055 package for awhile now with plans on adding I2C support relatively shortly.  might be of interest to you:

https://github.com/flynneva/bno055